# Javascript issue - Liferay 7.1 GA

Tags: javascript, frontend, liferay, liferay-7

I´ve been working in a website designed with Liferay 7.1 GA. I need to correct some accesibility issues so I´ve added some javascript scripts to execute in some pages. This scripts work correctly but at some point they stopped working correctly. I dont know why this is happening but analyzing the logs I found this error for every line of the scripts:

2021-06-28 09:32:33.680 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1281][UnicodeProperties:120] Invalid property on line }

How can I fix it?

Comment: try disabling Senna... https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360030752391-Disabling-SPA

Comment: I´ve added javascript.single.page.application.enabled = false
to the portal-ext.properties file and nothing happend. The scripts don´t work yet

Comment: post the script and the error

Comment: Hi Daniele, I´ve added a script to the javascript in the configuration of all pages and when I save it the portal doesn´t update it. When I save the changes this error appears in console: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'configureURL' of undefined The script isnt the problem cause it worked correctly days ago. I don´t know what happend.